# How to hide divs when livesearching with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a function in jQuery that, while typing, it *livesearch* divs with the same *h5* element (I know it could be a *class* or an *id*, but I'm making it like that because reasons). And when the searchbox is empty again, everything should be back to normal.

I'm using Bootstrap panels to achieve this also.

My jQuery code is this. I got it from another answer here, but modified a little for me needs:

```
//Se supone que busca. Lo plagié vilmente.
$("#busqueda").keyup(function(){

// Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
var filter = $(this).val();

// Loop through the comment list
$(".nombre").each(function(){

    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).attr("h5").contains(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();

        alert(filter);

    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
});
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 p1" data-clickstate="0">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_1">
                <div class="panel-body" style="display: inline" id="cat_1">

                    <div class="icono">
                        <img src="media/iconos/motores_busqueda.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nombre-y-des">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="nombre">Motores de búsqueda</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                            <p>Servicios de búqueda de páginas web.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_2">
                <div class="panel-body" id="cat_2" style="display: inline">
                    <div class="icono">
                        <img src="media/iconos/navegadores.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nombre-y-des">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="nombre">Navegadores</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                            <p>Programa que permite navegar por internet, renderizado páginas HTML en contenido visual y
                                comprensible.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_3">
                <div class="panel-body" id="cat_3" style="display: inline">
                    <div class="icono">
                        <img src="media/iconos/servidores_correo.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nombre-y-des">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="nombre">Servidores de correo</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                            <p>Servicio que permite enviar y recibir mensajes mediante sistemas de comunicación eletrónicos
                                en línea.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code should be looking the *h5* attribute to compare it with what is being typed, and therefore hide all other divs. Tho I think I'm missing something or I'm doing it all wrong. I'm not that experienced with jQuery.

This is the searchbox:

```
<div id="contenido">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="busqueda">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
                <div id="custom-search-input">
                    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Actividad a realizar, categorías, etc. (no olvides escribir los acentos correctamente ;~)"
                            id="inputBusqueda" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `#busqueda` element in your markup?

Comment: @yuriy636 Thanks, I forgot it.

Comment: there is no h5 attribute in your code, and what are you trying to do with .attr("h5") anyway?

Comment: `<h5 class="nombre">Motores de búsqueda</h5>` @aw04

Comment: that's an h5 element, not an attribute

Comment: Okai, sorry. Well that element. I'm trying to compare that with what is being typed on the searchbox. @aw04

Comment: in the question you say you're trying to use h5 instead of the classname, which would be fine except you loop based on the nombre class. you don't need to do it both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Case insensitive :contains | https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function(elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Se supone que busca. Lo plagié vilmente.
    $("#inputBusqueda").keyup(function() {
        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val();

        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".col-sm-4.col-md-4").each(function() {

            if ($(this).find('h5').is(':contains("' + filter + '")')) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

- Extra: the first thing is an snippet I found because I think users tend to search in lowercase; and it allows to search with insensitive case.
- Changed the id of the search input (`#inputBusqueda`).
- Redid all the "contains" part. In your code you were using `$.contains()` but like @Stu Cartwright said it's used for comparing element relations and such.
- The way I did it is simple: for each "column" we check if an `h5` child `:contain`s the `filter` value, if so we show it, else we hide it.

Check [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/L1t0wkyw/1/). Also if you want the search to be case sensitive, just get rid of the first part.

Comment: The snippet doesn't works but I'll try it on my code.

Comment: It works wonders. Thanks. And sorry for my ignorance about attributes and elements.

Answer (score 1):

attr("h5") isn't going to work, and you don't need it because you've already selected the h5 elements with the class "nombre".

[contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) may not do what you think it does. it's for checking parent/child relationship in the DOM (you may be confusing it with [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) )

To get the text of the nombre elements use just

```
$(this).text()
```

or

```
$(this).html()
```

Then run your regex on that.